# Generate a new variable/column in R based on recursively calling previous elements of a column without a for() loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, dplyr

I have some data in R that is organized in the following fashion (simplified example):

```
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(6,7,8,9,10)))
```

This creates a two-column dataframe ("V1" and "V2").  I want to create a third and fourth column ("V3" and "V4") that both invoke different functions based on previous entries in each of these two columns.  V3 is based on a function that constantly appends a vector, and V4 is a straightforward mathematical operation (geometric mean).  So far, I'm able to get what I need by designating new columns and using `for()` loops (example using simplified functions):

```
x <- x %>% mutate(V3 = 0, V4_0 = 0, V4 = 0)
for(i in 2:nrow(x)){x$V3[i] <- sum(c(x$V1[1:i - 1], x$V1[i] + x$V2[i]))}
for(i in 2:nrow(x)){x$V4_0[i] <- ((x$V2[i] - x$V2[i - 1]) / x$V2[i - 1])}
for(i in 2:nrow(x)){x$V4[i] <- prod(x$V4_0[1:i - 1] + 1, na.rm = TRUE)^(1/i) - 1}  # essentially, a geometric mean
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3      V4_0         V4
1  1  6  0 0.0000000 0.00000000
2  2  7 10 0.1666667 0.00000000
3  3  8 14 0.1428571 0.05272660
4  4  9 19 0.1250000 0.07456993
5  5 10 25 0.1111111 0.08447177
```

I'm curious: is there a cleaner or easier way to do this with tidyverse functions (e.g. `mutate()`) or base R?  Or are `for()` loops my best bet?  Everything works fine on a small scale but I'm worried about larger datasets since `for()` loops are supposedly less efficient.  I figure that `cumsum()` comes close to this but is case-specific to sums.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code has at least one mistake: `1:i - 1` is not the same as `1:(i-1)`. Notable is that indexing over `vec[1:i - 1]` is starting with a `0`, which is empty ... so you're getting fewer data than you think you are. (In this case, it appears to be a silent mistake that is masked/negated by the aggregating `sum`.)

Comment: I infer from your comment on `cumsum` that your logic (perhaps not included here) might be more complex. If that's the case, then **unless** you can capitalize on the efficiencies of `cumsum`, `cumprod`, and `diff` as I have in my answer, you might be stuck with doing it manually as above.

Comment: You make a good point: I should probably have just asked for my use-case instead of simplifying with different functions (perhaps incorrectly). The actual scenario is that V1 symbolizes cashflows, V2 symbolizes a running balance, V3 is the `irr()` function from the `jrvFinance` package that accepts a vector as a single argument, and V4 is a time-weighted rate of return (geometric mean).  Your answer works perfectly for V4, but for V3 I'd have to provide a vector first to satisfy the `irr()` function (unless there's some better base R mathematical way).  Thoughts?

Comment: Actually, tooling around a bit, I found that my original code for V4 was off.  Your methodology still stands, and the correct implementation for V4 is: `x$V4 <- c(1, cumprod(diff(x$V2) / x$V2[-nrow(x)] + 1)[-nrow(x)])^(1/seq_len(nrow(x))) - 1`, which obviates the need for `V4_0`.  All that said, I'm still not sure how to provide a vector for V3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
x$V3 <- c(0, cumsum(x$V1)[-1] + x$V2[-1])
x$V4_0 <- c(0, diff(x$V2) / x$V2[-nrow(x)])
x$V4 <- c(1, cumprod(x$V4_0 + 1)[-nrow(x)])^(1/seq_len(nrow(x))) - 1
x
#   V1 V2 V3      V4_0         V4
# 1  1  6  0 0.0000000 0.00000000
# 2  2  7 10 0.1666667 0.00000000
# 3  3  8 14 0.1428571 0.05272660
# 4  4  9 19 0.1250000 0.07456993
# 5  5 10 25 0.1111111 0.08447177
```

---

### Alternative #1

If there are scenarios where you cannot do things vectorized like this (e.g., if `jrvFinance::irr` needs to operate on a vector of length 2 for each new value), then I suggest `zoo::rollapply`:

```r
zoo::rollapply(seq_along(x$V1), 2, FUN = function(vec) {
  # ...
})
```

The inner function is called with a vector length 2; the first time is `c(1,2)`, second `c(2,3)`, etc. Normally, `rollapply` operates on the data itself (i.e., `x$V1`), but since you want to use both `V1` and `V2`, I'll roll on the index of the vectors instead of the vectors themselves.

That changes your

```r
sum(c(x$V1[1:i - 1], x$V1[i] + x$V2[i]))
```

to

```r
sum(c(x$V1[1:vec[1]], x$V1[vec[2]] + x$V2[vec[2]]))
```

Some more notes on this:

```r
zoo::rollapply(seq_along(x$V1), 2,
               FUN = function(vec) sum(c(x$V1[1:vec[1]], x$V1[vec[2]] + x$V2[vec[2]])))
# [1] 10 14 19 25
```

- This returns `2-1=1` element shorter than the input. (That is, if `rollapply(vec, 5, ...)`, then it would return 4 fewer elements than the input vector.) To remedy this, we can either manually pad it with `c(0, rollapply(...))`, or we can `fill=` the values.
- Rolling functions have the notion of `align`ment. From the help docs:

  ```
     align: specifyies whether the index of the result should be left- or
            right-aligned or centered (default) compared to the rolling
            window of observations. This argument is only used if 'width'
            represents widths.
  ```

  And a demo of them:

  ```r
  zoo::rollapply(1:5, 3, sum, align = "left", fill = NA)
  # [1]  6  9 12 NA NA
  zoo::rollapply(1:5, 3, sum, align = "center", fill = NA)
  # [1] NA  6  9 12 NA
  zoo::rollapply(1:5, 3, sum, align = "right", fill = NA)
  # [1] NA NA  6  9 12
  ```

  Where my interpretation of `align="left"` is that the output goes in the left-most slot of the three values (here) used to generate the sum. That is,

  ```
  1  2  3  4  5
  `-----' sum these
  ^       align="left", output goes here
     ^    align="center", output goes here
        ^ align="right", output goes here
  ```

  (Realize that `align=` does nothing without `fill=something`.)

So using `align=` and `fill=`, we can now do:

```r
x$V3_again <- zoo::rollapply(seq_along(x$V1), 2,
                             FUN = function(vec) sum(c(x$V1[1:vec[1]], x$V1[vec[2]] + x$V2[vec[2]])),
                             align = "right", fill = 0)
x
#   V1 V2 V3      V4_0         V4 V3_again
# 1  1  6  0 0.0000000 0.00000000        0
# 2  2  7 10 0.1666667 0.00000000       10
# 3  3  8 14 0.1428571 0.05272660       14
# 4  4  9 19 0.1250000 0.07456993       19
# 5  5 10 25 0.1111111 0.08447177       25
```

---

### Alternative #2

```r
inds <- seq_len(nrow(x))
c(0, mapply(function(a,b) sum(c(x$V1[1:a], x$V1[b] + x$V2[b])), 
            inds[-length(inds)], inds[-1]))
# [1]  0 10 14 19 25
```

(The `c(0, ...)` is mimicking `rollapply`'s `align="right",fill=0` arguments.)

`mapply` is similar to `lapply`/`sapply`/`vapply`, but while those three functions operate on a single vector at a time, `mapply` works on one or more vectors, effectively "zipping" them together. For example,

```r
mapply(FUN, 1:5, 6:10)
```

unrolls to effectively call

```r
FUN(1, 6)
FUN(2, 7)
FUN(3, 8)
FUN(4, 9)
FUN(5, 10)
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  I tested both of your solutions, and they both work flawlessly.  By my measurements, the `mapply` function is appears to be slightly faster, although the `zoo::rollapply` method seems far more flexible and broadly applicable.  I learned a ton from this---thank you so much for your help!